# Show that there is $c \in (-1,2)$ such that $f'(c)=0$.

Tags: derivatives, functional-equations

$f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ differentible function and $F:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a primitive of $f$. We know $5F(xy^{2}-y)+F(x^{2}y-x)-F(x^{3}-y)F(2xy-2)\geq 9$ for every $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$. Show that there is $c \in (-1,2)$ such that $f'(c)=0$.
I think that inequality somehow is related to a function that is positive and somehow we need to use Rolle's Thoerem with that function.

Comment: Is there something else you can add on this problem? 

One can show, that $F(0) = F(3) = 3$ at the points $(x,y) = (1,1)$, $(x,y) = (-1,-1)$ and $(x,y) = (2,2)$. Then, you can define a function $g(x)$ for $x=y$ such that $$g(x) =: 6F(x^3 - x) - F(x^3 - x)F(2x^2 - 2).$$
Then, you can show that there is $c \in (-1, 2)$ s.t. $g''(c)=0$. But, I don't see how this implies that $f''(c)=0$.